# Intuit Customer Data Internal Server Error

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

When entering multiple mfa question responses I receive an internal server error, but I am still able to receive the transactions from an account.  Below is the flow that I am currently using which throws the error.

I grab the institution details via the GetInstitutionDetails(long institutionId);

I present the user with the first set of questions that they must answer and use their response with the DiscoverAndAddAccounts(long institutionId, InstitutionLogin login, out challenges, out challengeSession);

The user is presented with one mfa question.  The user responds to the question and I call
DiscoverAndAddAccountsResponse(challengeResponses, challengeSession);

I then update the institution login to determine if there are more questions to ask with the following call.

UpdateInstitutionLogin(InstitutionLoginId, login, true, out challenges, out challengeSessions);

When the user responds to these questions and I once again call
DiscoverAndAddAccountsResponse(challengeResponses, challengeSession) with the new responses I receive and internal server error exception, but the account goes from "CHALLENGE_RESPONSE_REQUIRED" to "NOT_NECESSARY" and I am able to grab transaction data.

Comment: What language are you working in?  Is the remote server (Intuit's) the one throwing the Internal Server Error?  If so, have you contacted their support folks?  ISEs usually indicate a server-side problem.

Comment: This is with C#.  The internal server error is in fact the remote server.  I have since contacted their support and found peter's response below to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be calling UpdateInstitutionLoginResponse rather than DiscoverAndAddResponse if you are passing back challenges from the UpdateInstitutionLogin call.